# Smooth 4-genus not agreeing with topological 4-genus intuition

Tags: surfaces, knot-theory, knot-invariants

I am aware that there are many examples of knots which have different topological 4-genus than smooth 4-genus (11n_34 is the one with the least amount of crossings, it is topologically slice but has smooth 4 genus equal to 1). I want to intuitively understand why this is, just like I intuitively understand why there are knots which are slice but have 3-genus non-zero. Does anybody have a good visualization or idea to understand this phenomena intuitively? Thanks for any help.

Comment: This is a good question.  I wish I knew the answer.  I am looking forward to someone giving a helpful response.  But if no one does, perhaps MO is a better venue to ask?

Comment: @N.Owad Thanks, I am looking forward to that aswell. I read somewhere that one should do this only after a week or two has passed without an answer (as a rule).

Comment: Unfortunately, because of the nonconstructive nature of Freedman's work, there is no way to visualise the TOP-genus minimising surface. As close as you can get to intuition might be that "if enough invariants behave correctly (here the Alexander polynomial being 1), then appropriate uses of the Freedman machine ensure the existence of the surface in question". I don't know of an instance where the "Freedman-disc" for an Alexander polynomial one knot can be seen explicitly.